# Wordpress CodeMirror.fromTextArea is not a function error

Tags: wordpress, codemirror

I am using code mirror editor from wordpress bundle in a plugin page. I have enqueued the following styles and scripts as per some research [here](https://wpreset.com/add-codemirror-editor-plugin-theme/).

```
wp_enqueue_style('wp-codemirror');
$cm_settings['codeEditor'] = wp_enqueue_code_editor(array('type' => 'text/css'));
$var = array(
    'cm_settings'   => $cm_settings
);
wp_localize_script('my-admin-script', 'my_var', $var);
```

Then in my js file, i have added the following line to make the textarea `my_textarea` to code editor.

```
 wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#my_textarea'), my_var.cm_settings);
```

Everything works fine. I am not able to get value from the code mirror editor. I tried

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("my_textarea"));
console.log(editor.getValue());
```

But i am getting an error saying `CodeMirror.fromTextArea is not a function`. I have been stuck at this the whole day. Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was solved on setting a variable,

```
var editor = wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#my_textarea'), my_var.cm_settings);
```

and accessing the varibale `editor`, you can do anything.

for eg: you can use `editor.codemirror.getValue()` to access the value. You don't need to use CodeMirror.fromTextArea here.